# error while populating a drop down from json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate a button drop down in angularjs. 
I am getting the following error. `"Unexpected end of expression: data.WotcSummary "|` What am I doing wrong.

js file :

```
WotcDashBoardModule.controller('WotcDashBoardController', ['$scope', 'WotcDashBoardModuleService', function ($scope, WotcDashBoardModuleService) {

     var Ein = '95-000000'; 
    WotcDashBoardModuleService.GetDashBoardSummary(Ein).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Summary = response.data.WotcSummary;
        //console.log($scope.Summary.Locations);
    });

}]);
```

Locations is an array with two items

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"California"
__proto__:Object
1:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"Atlanta"
__proto__:Object
2:Object
corporateId:1600
```

location:"Boston"

HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toolbar btn-margin-left" style="float: right;" >
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ALL LOCATIONS
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <select name="ListLocations" class="form-control input-md"                                                              
                                ng-model="Locations" 
                                ng-options="Locations.location for Locations in data.WotcSummary | track by Locations.location">
                            <option value=""> </option>
                        </select>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The Business Object class thats being returned to the view is :

```
public class CompanyWotcBO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public int IdCandidate { get; set; }
        public int DocsSubmitted { get; set; }
        public int DocsRecieved { get; set; }       
        public string CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string EIN { get; set; }
        public string Error { get; set; }

        public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }      

        public CompanyWotcBO()
            {
            Locations = new List<Location>();
            }

    }

    public class Location
    {
        public int corporateId { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
```

Here  is the full json object that gets returned ::

```
Object {Id: 0, IdUser: 0, IdCandidate: 0, NewEmployees: 458, WotcScreened: 458…}
CompanyId:null
DocsRecieved:0
DocsSubmitted:0
EIN:null
Error:null
Id:0
IdCandidate:0
IdUser:0
Locations:Array[3]
0:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"95-3874566"
__proto__:Object
1:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"Atlanta"
__proto__:Object
2:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"Boston"
__proto__:Object
3:Object
corporateId:1600
location:"Chicago"
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: can you post object here please?

Comment: posted the object. is that the one you were expecting.

Comment: ng-model="Locations", is that an object, id or string? can you also share its value?

Comment: Locations is an object. I pasted the full json object in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need `'|'` in a ng-options

```
 <select name="ListLocations" class="form-control input-md"                                                              
                                ng-model="Locations" 
                                ng-options="Locations.location for Locations in data.WotcSummary track by Locations.location">
                        <option value=""> </option>
```

Comment: thank u. I dont' see the eror but, the dropdown is not getting populated.

Comment: post your data in the question

Comment: @BumbleBee Post the json data

Comment: its not a json, could you please apply JSON.stringify(j);

Answer (score 1):

Change you HTML to:

```
<select name="ListLocations" class="form-control input-md"                                                              
                                ng-model="Locations" 
                                ng-options="Locations as Locations.location for Locations in data.WotcSummary track by Locations.location">
                        <option value=""> </option>
```

This should work

Comment: I am getting the following error : Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'Locations as Locations.location'. Element: {1}

Comment: It may be because the ng-model value and the ng-options variable name is same. try doing this ng-options="Location as Location.location for Location in data.WotcSummary track by Location.location">

Comment: ng-options="Location as Location.location for Location in summary. Locations track by Location.location">

Comment: would be better if you can share the stringified object form that you receive as response. You can try the above once though